# Drools [Test Scenario]: load field of type date

Tags: drools

I have serveral datasets with Date type fields and I want to create a test scenario without change the data type (from date to LocalDate). 
is it posssible? If it is possible, How ?
If I try load a date , it return "date don't support".

Comment: "date don't support" isn't something that would be returned by Drools. Please show your code, how you're executing your rules, an example of your rule, and the actual error (with stack trace if an exception) that is occurring.

Comment: The message error in test scenario is "Mensaje de error: Class java.util.Date is not supported". The DataSet  has defined the folowing attribute. " private Date fecha_factura".

Comment: So, if I want to use test scenario and in my data objects have defined fields with data type Date, I have to change the data  type in all data objects to LocalDate. Are there any workarround without change the data type in the data objects?

Comment: added the stack:17:28:24,020 ERROR [org.drools.scenariosimulation.backend.runner.RuleScenarioRunnerHelper] (default task-3) Error in GIVEN data FactIdentifier{name='1|1', className='com.myspace.facturacion.CFECabezalDto'}: Error in one or more input values: org.drools.scenariosimulation.backend.runner.ScenarioException: Error in one or more input values
        at org.drools.scenariosimulation.backend.runner.AbstractRunnerHelper.getParamsFor

Comment: Under your question is a button that says [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62393743/edit). If you click that you can put this information into your question directly instead of in comments.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR
You can use a MVEL expression if you want to use a Date: just write in the cell # and then your expression. For example `# new java.util.Date(....)`.

Long version
Test Scenario supports as native types only a subset of Java types: string, boolean, integer, long, double, float, char, byte, short, localdate and enum (enum since 7.39 that will be released soon).
For all these types there is a literal version that makes possible to recognize it just parsing the value.
For all other java types you should use a MVEL expression.
We recently changed the error message to refers to MVEL and it will be part of 7.39

Links

[Test Scenario documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#test-designer-expressions-syntax-rule-based-ref)

[Scenario Cheatsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEcO4.png)

Comment: Hi Daniele, I tried with MVEL as you suggest and it worked, thank you very much.